# Delauny Triangulation Overlapping Across Rows

Tags: python, computational-geometry, mesh, geo

I am trying to fetch Digital Elevation Model data from a WMS (this works) and output an .obj file of the model (this doesn't).

It mostly works, and you can see real geologic features in the data, however there are strange spikes where there are triangles connected across rows.

Here is my code, to run it you need to install the libraries, create a file called `model.obj` in the directory you're running it from, and you're good to go.

https://pastebin.com/raw/UiMKKhW3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obj files are indexed starting at 1, and the array indices for the triangles start at 0.  To fix, simply write

`f.write("f " + str(simplex[0] + 1) + " " + str(simplex[1] + 1) + " " + str(simplex[2] + 1) + '\n')`

instead of

`f.write("f " + str(simplex[0]) + " " + str(simplex[1]) + " " + str(simplex[2]) + '\n')`